# How to handle unanswered duplicates where you can answer them

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In a tag I follow, two questions that are duplicates of eachother have been posted by different users (in relatively quick succession). There's no old duplicate I could find.

It's a relatively easy to answer question, and I've answered the first (also best written) one. However, that answer has not yet been accepted nor has been upvoted.

My topic for discussion is: what to do with the second one? It already has a comment by a different user referring to the first one. I can't mark it as a duplicate, since the first one doesn't have an accepted or upvoted answer.

It's considerably less effort and less well written than the first one, and already has a too broad vote, but I'd prefer it closed as a duplicate.

Comment: That particular "dupe" could also be closed as "too broad", couldn't it?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't consider the underlying question too broad, but that second one isn't well written, and could be closed as too broad. However, that's not my preference (and the user might find the first one (since that's linked in a comment), and think _hey, why didn't he get closed too?_).

Comment: I mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311167/button-to-move-one-record-from-one-table-to-another) one. There is almost no question at all.

Comment: Yes, it's very low-effort. But the solution is 100% exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311167), which does show effort. Luckily, someone was nice enough to make me able to close it as a dupe, which makes this question less relevant.

Comment: Not so sure this needs to be hurried, trash ought to be deleted instead.  But I'll take your word for it, done.

Comment: @HansPassant Feel free to remove the vote from my question ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49314805/7296893)), the question has been marked as a dupe. I've edited, so you should be able to. I'd be glad if you did, since I feel bad for asking for votes in an indirect way.